# How do I get the size of a varying-depth JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been at this all day, trying to write a recursive function in Javascript to get the sizes. I need some help :/

Basically, my JSON object contains hierarchical categories/subcategories. I'd like to determine the size of each category/subcategory.

Here is a simple demonstration: http://pastehtml.com/view/bkpzzlabs.html

I'd like to take the JSON on the left and get the HTML on the right. Perhaps I've just been staring at this computer monitor for too long because for the life of me I can't figure this out.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Have you written any code at all?  Please show what you have.

Comment: @Hogan http://codepad.org/Wjlr1rJW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side of your "demonstration" suggests that you don't just want to recursively count the total number of endpoints (or "leafs") in your JSON; you want to know the recursive size for each category (non-leaf node) in the tree. The key here is that the nodes in between the leafs and the root don't count.

> **Update:** I updated the function; read below.

Try this:

```
function parseTree(parent) {
    var hasNonLeafNodes = false;
    var childCount = 0;
    
    for (var child in parent) {
        if (typeof parent[child] === 'object') {
            // Parse this sub-category:
            childCount += parseTree(parent[child]);
            // Set the hasNonLeafNodes flag (used below):
            hasNonLeafNodes = true;
        }
    }
    
    if (hasNonLeafNodes) {
        // Add 'num_children' element and return the recursive result:
        parent.num_children = childCount;
        return childCount;
    } else {
        // This is a leaf item, so return 1:
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This function will **modify** the original object, so that a new key `'num_children'` is added to each non-leaf node in the tree. The function **returns** the total number of leaf nodes in all of the `parent`'s descendants. Note that it's also perfectly possible to call this function on a subset of your object.

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/CXXaB/

> Sorry about that! I had to do something else for a bit and, apparently, forgot what it was I was doing here... ;-)
>
> The updated solution should count the addresses correctly, but keep in mind that arrays can't have named keys (such as `num_children`). This is relevant in your example as e.g. "Pothole" is an array.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that! It looks like the num_children value is actually _double_ what it's supposed to be, but I'm looking through now to see if I can fix that.

Comment: @Tobias: oops, sorry about! Had a bit of a brain lapse there. See my update. :-)

Comment: Fantastic! Do you know how to get it to do the counts for the array parts? For example, it doesn't give the num_children for 'Pothole' because it's a [] array, but it will count 'Abandoned Building' because it's a {} object.

Comment: Seems I got it to work by just adding a key to the arrays. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague. I guess What you need is something analogous to deepcopy. Following is function for deepcopy.

```
function deepCopy(p) {
    var c = {};
    for (var i in p) {
          if (typeof p[i] === 'object') {
            c[i] = (p[i].constructor === Array)?[]:{};
            deepCopy(p[i],c[i]);
          } 
    else {
            c[i] = p[i];
          }
    }
    return c;
    }
```

Customize the above deepcopy function for your application.